# File default.css appears in browser after being deleted from server

Tags: file, browser, cloudflare

I am making some changes to the css file for a website and I found out that my changes are disregarded. 
In order to diagnose the problem, I deleted the only css file I have (default.css) from the server.
To my surprise, all web browers (Chrome, Firefox, IE11) are still capable of seeing and downloading the file. So, if I go to www.example.com/default.css, I can download the file despite the fact it is not there anymore! I used the command Ctrl + F5 to clear the local cash from browsers and reload the file default.css, but the file is still there and it contains the old version. I also used Ctrl + Shift + Del to clear everything in IE browser. Earlier today I created the file .htaccess to redirect example.com to www.example.com. I also use the services of cloudflare. 
If I upload to the same location a different file, default2.css, I can view it correctly. 
Any idea who delivers to me the old file? I suspect it may be cloudflare. I host my website on runhosting.com

Thanks,
Nick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you [purge the file in CloudFlare](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200169386-How-do-I-purge-a-single-file-from-cache-)?

CSS is a file CloudFlare caches & you would want to purge it if you make a change to [static content](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200172516-What-file-extensions-does-CloudFlare-cache-for-static-content-) we cache.

Comment: Thanks for info. I will do that next time when I need it.